# How can a particle's position and velocity be the same all the time?

Tags: kinematics, velocity

I have an $x-t$ graph (position-time) which its equation is $x=e^t$.

If we get derivative of it, the velocity's equation will be $e^t$ too.

How can a particle's position and velocity be the same? what does it mean when position and velocity are the same? is there any real examples of it?

Comment: Hi everybody -- I've removed some comments that are attempting to answer the question. If you have an answer, please post it as an answer. Comments are for seeking clarification or suggesting improvements. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that these quantities have units. What does $\exp\left(1\,\mathrm{s}\right)$ mean? How does it compare to $\exp\left(1\,\mathrm{min}\right)$?

Generally you can only take non-polynomial functions* of dimensionless quantities. So for your expression to make sense it should be something like 
$$
x = x_0 e^{t/t_0}
$$
Now it may be that $x_0 = 1\,\mathrm{m}$ and $t_0 = 1\,\mathrm{s}$, in which case, in SI units, it will numerically look like $x=e^t$, but if we change units to say miles and days this will no longer be true.

If we take the derivative of this equation we find that 
$$
 v = \frac{x_0}{t_0}e^{t/t_0}
$$
which is clearly not the same as the previous equation,(although again, if we make a particular choice of units it may look the same).

*logarithms are a bit of an odd case here. If I have an expression like $\log t/t_0$ then I can (formally at least) use rules of logarithms to write this as $\log t - \log t_0$. This appears to the logarithm of a dimensionful quantity, but if you make a change of units you will find that numerically everything cancels out. Generally I find it is safer and makes more sense to simply say that the logarithm identities only apply to dimensionless quantities and so disallow the second expression, but some people use other conventions.

Comment: Hi, just came back to this. You said if we set $x_0=1s$ and $t_0=1s$ we have the same formulas for position and velocity. Can you please explain how it is perceived if the position and velocity are always the same? Are there real examples too?

Comment: The point is that the statement "position and velocity are always the same" doesn't really make sense. They have different units, so even if you pick units so that it is true for a given set of units that doesn't mean anything physical

Comment: When I say "always" I mean always in the graph curves of the position-time and velocity-time of the same units.

Comment: What do you mean that doesn't mean anything physical?

Comment: Position and velocity *don't* have the same units. That is the problem

Comment: I mean position and time. $x_0=1m$ and $t_0=1s$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no physical significance of the equations velocity and position w.r.t time being same simultaneously but what we can understand from this is that both phenomenon change simultaneously
It is possible for position and velocity to be same but both of them depend on the frame of reference at any point of time the position and velocity are same w.r.t. independent frames or the same frame as it is in this case

Hope you got that!